# C++: how do I assign values to a list of vectors efficiently?

Tags: c++, list, stl, vector

Reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826935/how-do-i-store-arrays-in-an-stl-list), I've decided I need to use something like this:

`list<vector<double> > psips;`

for a simulation in c++. The question is, what is the simplest (and a reasonably efficient) way of initiating a list like this containing `N` vectors with `d` zeros in each?

Cheers!

Comment: Are you sure you need `std::vector` (dynamically resizable), and not `std::array` (size fixed at compile-time)?

Comment: @sbi, no I'm not. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: `std::array` is part of the next C++ standard, currently expected end of this year. It might already be available with your std lib. If not, there likely is `std::tr1::array`. And if your compiler doesn't have that either (highly unlikely), there's always `boost::array`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::list<std::vector<double> > psips(N, std::vector<double>(d));
```

See #3 [here](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/container/list/constructor) and #2 [here](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/container/vector/constructor).

Comment: you need to provide a default value for your double, otherwise it will fill it with junk as double default constructor just sets the double to whatever (junk) is in memory: `std::list<std::vector<double> > psips(N, std::vector<double>(d, 0));`

Comment: @jules : No you don't. Quoting the second link: "2) constructs the container with count copies of elements with value `T()`." `double()` is guaranteed by the standard to be `0.`.

Comment: Ok, it must be a misunderstanding from my part. I thought that double() was not initializing the value to zero, but to what is in memory, which lead to undefined behaviour. I guess I was wrong

Comment: @jules : While many compilers have been known to implement this incorrectly until quite recently (notoriously, VC++), the standard guarantees this behavior in §8.5/5: "To zero-initialize an object of type T means: if T is a scalar type, the object is set to the value of 0 (zero) converted to T." The boost.value_initialized library exists largely to work around those compiler deficiencies.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the stl constructor, and set the default value to zero:

`explicit vector ( size_type n, const T& value= T());`
`explicit list ( size_type n, const T& value = T())`

So what you would do is:

`vector< double > example( d, 0);`

`list< vector < double > > your_list(N, example);`

And you have a list of N vector and d vector with zeros in it.

Comment: Note that you wouldn't need to pass the second parameter (`0`) to the vector's constructor, as this is the default.

Comment: +1 for constructing a vector only once. (Other answers are constructing the vector for each instance)

Comment: @Basilevs, the answer provided by @ildjarn also only constructs the vector exactly as many times as this answer does. The `N` copies of the vector are all copy-constructed the temporary that @ildjarn passes in, just as the N copies of @jules vector are copy constructed from the named object he passes in.

Answer (score 1):

```
 std::list<std::vector<double> > psips(100, std::vector<double>(10, 20.0));
```

Each vector in the list is having `10` elements, each initialized with `20.0`. And total number of such vectors in the list is `100`.