# Collection of int/string[] with one line of code for each insertion

Tags: c++, string, std

I need to create a collection of key/value pairs like this:

```
map<const int, string[]> myMap; // psuedo code
```

What would be the best way of going about it?
Is there a way to do it where i can initialize it in one line like:

```
myMap.Insert(1, new string[]{ "stack", "is", "awesome" }); // pseudo code
```

Comment: Why are you using a `string` array (which is actually a `string` pointer, here)? Why not use a `vector<string>` and avoid `new`?

Comment: Thank you, that is something i overlooked. I'll look into it now.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan: The code [doesn't even compile](http://ideone.com/pOh4S).

Comment: Because you [can't store arrays in containers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/826949/726361) (I sense a C# programmer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you decide to stick with roughly the structure you're currently using (with `int` as the key and a collection of `string`s as the associated value) you probably want to use `std::vector<std::string>` as the value, so your `map` is defined like:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<std::string> > mymap;
```

In this case, it's probably easiest to use array-like notation to do your insertion:

```
mymap[1] = {"String", "is", "awesome"};
```

As it stands, this depends on using a C++11 braced initializer list. That will work with the newest compilers (e.g., gcc 4.7.0) but fail on many that are older are not yet as close to conforming with C++11 (e.g., VC++10, VC++11 beta).

Comment: You are correct. This is exactly what i was looking for. Unfortunately its not available atm in vs2010. But since it will basically work in immediate future i will mark it as the answer.

As far as my current problem went, i solved it by creating an ellipsis function of char* that returned a vector<string> so i can call it like this:

map<int, vector<string>> myMap;
myMap[1] = charStringsToVector("word1","word2",NULL);

Answer (score 1):

You can use the utility function **[make_pair](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/make_pair/)**.

```
myMap.insert(make_pair(1,"stack"));
```

Not sure Why you would need a `string []`, you can have multiple strings refereed by an unique key isn't that the purpose of selecting an `std::map`? Why would you need a array then `std::map` provides that already.

Comment: Oh you mean like having multiple values per key?

Comment: @PrivateVoid: Multiple values per key is what [**std::multimap**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multimap/) provides you. Why not use a `std::multimap` if that be the requirment.

Comment: I could, but the cleanest way i can think of is having an array of string returned by a key. Basically this in C#:

words.Add(1, new string[]{ "Word1", "word2", "banana" });

Mainly for code readability, as this would be a long list.
I guess i can just wrap it in a function. Thanks for your help, but none of it really solved what i was originally asking.

Comment: @PrivateVoid: Because what you asked cannot be done in C++, You cannot store arrays in Standard Library containers because arrays are not assignable and container elements need to be assignable.

Comment: Als you are correct. Thank you for trying to help. I learned from you today.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care whether you are replacing or creating just use `operator[]`.

```
    std::map<int, std::string> mymap;
    mymap[1] = "stack is awesome";
```

And don't use pointers in the map. Or use `std::multimap` for multiple elements with the same key.

Example with `std::multimap`:

```
int main() {
    std::multimap<int, std::string> mymmap{{1, "stack"},
                       {1, "is"},
                       {1, "awesome"}};
    auto range = mymmap.equal_range(1);
    for (auto i = range.first; i != range.second; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << (*i).second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: @PrivateVoid: `map<const int, string[]> myMap;` is not labeled pseudo-code.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at std::multimap, it may fit your use cases better:

```
multimap<int, string> mm;
```

Its the same as map except that it can hold multiple values for the same key.  This is generally implemented by a binary tree that simply doesn't enforce uniqueness.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap

Or you can use:

```
map<int, vector<string>> m;
```

You can initialize like this:

```
map<int, vector<string>> m {
    { 1, { "stack", "is", "awesome" } },
    { 42, { "foo", "bar", "baz" } }
};
```